# Feature To Provision Managed Metadata Service

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint-2010

I created a PowerShell script which:

1. Uses Get-SPServiceApplicationPool, Get-SPMetadataServiceApplicationProxy and Get-SPMetadataServiceApplication to check if the service is already configured
2. Uses the corresponding Remove-* cmdlets to remove the application pool, proxy and service if they exist
3. Uses the corresponding New-* cmdlets to create the application pool, proxy and service
4. Enables the taxonomy and metadata navigation features if not enabled
5. Creates and populates a group and term sets

I would like to implement this in C# as a feature with a feature event reciever in the FeatureActivated event. I hit the first problem (there may be more) during the very first step. After trying to figure out how to get the SPIisWebServiceApplicationPool from C# on my own for a while, I decompiled Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell to see how the Get-SPServiceApplicationPool cmdlet is implemented and it's done by accessing SPIisWebApplicationSettings in the Microsoft.SharePoint assembly. It uses the SPIisWebApplicationSettings.Default.ApplicationPools enumeration. That class is marked internal and access to it is allowed from the Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell assembly by the inclusion of an InternalsVisibleTo attribute on the Microsoft.SharePoint assembly.

So, without hacking and recompiling the Microsoft.SharePoint assembly to give my assembly InternalsVisibleTo access and without hosting PowerShell within my feature, how can I check if the SPIisWebServiceApplicationPool exists, remove it if it does and then create a new SPIisWebServiceApplicationPool? Also, using reflection to get access to the internal classes isn't prefered... I'm looking for what I'm missing in the SharePoint API that will let me do this.